# How combine local variable in Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I want to convert procedure from sqlserver into oracle 11g.
This is my sp in sqlserver

```
declare
@nwhere varchar(200);
@Select varchar(200);
@from varchar(200);
@final varchar(200);

set @select='select * '
set @from='from table '
set @where='where 1=1'
set @final=@select+@from+@where

execute (@final)
```

How combine local variable in oracle like `@final=@select+@from+@where?`
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Oracle procedure would look something like:

```
declare
  v_where varchar2(200);
  v_select varchar2(200);
  v_from varchar2(200);
  v_final varchar2(600);
begin
  v_select := 'select * ';
  v_from := 'from table ';
  v_where := 'where 1 = 1';
  v_final := v_select || v_from || v_where;
end;
/
```

N.B. I've changed the variables to be prefaced with "v_" instead of "@", because Oracle doesn't like identifiers that begin with non-alpha characters, and also because just leaving the "@" off could confuse the code, since select, from and where are reserved words.

Note also that I've extended the length of the v_final variable to 600, since the previous 3 strings could be 200 characters each, and 200*3 does not fit into 200 characters!

I've excluded running the query, as you haven't said what you need doing with it. In Oracle, if you run a select statement in PL/SQL, you need to store the results somewhere. This could be bulk collecting them into a collection or looping through the results and storing each row in a record or set of variables.

Or you could simply pass the query back to the calling code as a ref cursor, which then allows the calling code to fetch results back from the query as if it had run the sql directly itself.

In short, if you want to know how to run the select statement in pl/sql, you'll need to provide more information about what you're going to do with it next. Are you inserting somewhere? Updating something? etc

Comment: I want to select something. also I want dynamic sql so I need merge/join local variable

Comment: But once you've done the select, what will you be doing with the data?

Comment: Also what is calling this procedure? Is it an ad-hoc thing, or is it something that you'll be putting into a stored procedure? Working with totally dynamic sql can be a bit of a pain - if you don't know what columns might be returned and you need to access said columns in PL/SQL, then you won't be able to use native dynamic sql (aka `execute immediate`). Instead, you're going to have to use the procedures from the dbms_sql package to process the query. But, depending on what you do with the query, this could be overkill.

Comment: `execute immediate` dynamic sql and then returning result into local variable is a normal practice for example `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING emp_id RETURNING INTO salary;`

Comment: @are Yes, it is. But that assumes you know the columns being returned by sql_stmt. If you don't know or it could change from call to call, it's problematic.

Comment: `dbms_sql vs execute immediate` - too broad question, discussion about this is here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1253651449550

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate strings with the || operator:

```
DECLARE
  v_where VARCHAR2(200);
  v_select VARCHAR2(200);
  v_from VARCHAR2(200);
  v_final VARCHAR2(200); 
  v_row table%ROWTYPE;
  c_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  v_select := 'select * ';
  v_from := 'from table ';
  v_where := 'where 1=1';
  v_final :=  v_select || from || where;

  OPEN c_cursor FOR v_final;
  FETCH c_cursor INTO v_row; 
  CLOSE c_cursor;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

concatenate strings with the **||** operator

if you need keep IDs of vars as is with **@** you need add **"**

do execute your statement you need use [execute immediate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm) 
or [dbms_sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF)

```
declare
"@select" varchar(200) := 'select * ';
"@from" varchar(200) := ' from table ';
"@where" varchar(200) := ' where 1=1';
"@final" varchar(200) :="@select"||"@from"||"@where";
begin
  --test result string
  --dbms_output.put_line("@final");

  --execute
  execute immediate "@final";
end;
```

--oracle doesn't like **@** symbol, if you change it:

```
declare
vselect varchar(200) := 'select * ';
vfrom varchar(200) := ' from table ';
vwhere varchar(200) := ' where 1=1';
vfinal varchar(200) :=vselect||vfrom||vwhere;
begin
  --test result string
  --dbms_output.put_line(vfinal);

  --execute
  execute immediate vfinal;
end;
```

p.s. difference between dbms_sql vs execute immediate see here
[ask tom dbms_sql vs execute immediate](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1253651449550)

Comment: The `@` is required by T-SQL to identify a variable. It's not really part of the name. SQL Server apparently needs this to distinguish between variable references and e.g. column names.

Answer (score 0):

To append variables in oracle it is like

final=select || from || where

Answer (score 0):

use concat function or concat operator (||)oracle

```
DECLARE
  v_where  VARCHAR2(200);
  v_Select VARCHAR2(200);
  v_from   VARCHAR2(200);
  v_final  VARCHAR2(200);
  v_result VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  v_Select:='select 1 ';
  v_from  :='from dual ';
  v_where :='where sysdate=sysdate';
  v_final :=concat(concat(v_select,v_from),v_where);

  EXECUTE immediate v_final INTO v_result;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
END;
```

or

```
DECLARE
  v_where  VARCHAR2(200);
  v_Select VARCHAR2(200);
  v_from   VARCHAR2(200);
  v_final  VARCHAR2(200);
  v_result VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  v_Select:='select 1 ';
  v_from  :='from dual ';
  v_where :='where sysdate=sysdate';
  v_final :=(v_select||v_from||v_where);
  EXECUTE immediate v_final INTO v_result;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
END;
```